# Magento : Filter Collection by Attribute that Doesn't Exist or Null or another condition

Tags: magento-1.9, collection, product-collection, attribute-set

I have created a new product eav attribute, assume it is created correctly.
Now I write something in this attribute in some products (5 for example), and I delete it from some of them (4). So this attribute only exist in 5 products, one is written and other 4 are null, but it doesn't exist yet in rest of products.

How do I get all product which don't have that attribute set or have it null?

I can do it with ones that have this value set:

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
      ->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'newfield'))
      ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=> 'newfield','null' => true),
            array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => '')
        ));
```

But it returns me only the 4 products that I have written and erased 'newfield', and not rest of products that doesn't have it set yet.

**Edit:**

I found a half solution ([Filter collection by existence of attribute](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/3236/filter-collection-by-existence-of-attribute)).

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
      ->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'gtin'))
      ->addAttributeToFilter('newfield', array('null' => true), 'left');
```

I do not understand the third argument 'left', but this one returns me all the products with **NULL** in the **newfield** or where it does not exist yet (more than 13000 products), but I want to make an **OR** condition, I also want the products that contains **string(0) ""** or **string(8) "NO FIELD"**

I tried

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
      ->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'newfield'))
      ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=> 'newfield','null' => true, 'left'),
            array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => ''),
            array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => 'NO FIELD')
        ));
```

But it is not acting like an **OR** condition and I only get back 3 results instead of more than 13000, probably it is because i'm not using the third argument 'left' properly.

**Edit2:**

I finally found something about the third parameter 'left' here (http://blog.adin.pro/2013-03-07/left-join-on-addattributetofilter-with-eav-tables/). But I see that I'm using like this in my **OR** condition and still getting only 3 results instead of more than 13000. What am I doing wrong here?

**Edit3: Seems a definitive solution**

I finally found this (https://hannah.wf/snippet-magento-using-or-and-left-join-in-addattributetofilter/), and then I made it:

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
      ->getCollection()
      ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'newfield'))
      ->addAttributeToFilter(
        array(
            array('attribute'=> 'newfield','null' => true),
            array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => ''),
            array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => 'NO FIELD')
        ),
        '',
        'left');
```

It seems to return all the products I'm looking for, but I don't understand why it has to end with:

```
[...]
,
'',
'left');
```

My own logic says it should be

```
[...]
,
'left', //for the first condition
'',     //for the second condition
'');    //for the thrid condition
```

but my logic is returning only 3 results, so it's not working. The first one seems to work fine, but I don't understand why `'', 'left'`.

Comment: check after removing `array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => '')` from filter

Comment: remove `array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => '')` it's not working. Leaving  `array('attribute'=> 'newfield','null' => true) only ` only returns the products where the  `newfield ` is set and is  `NULL `, the only difference is that the products where the fields contain a string(0) ""  are not returned.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

After some tests, the code I wrote in the third edit of the question seems to work fine, so I think it is the correct answer:

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
  ->getCollection()
  ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'newfield'))
  ->addAttributeToFilter(
    array(
        array('attribute'=> 'newfield','null' => true),
        array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => ''),
        array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => 'NO FIELD')
    ),
    '',
    'left');
```

I checked it and it returns me the products where the **newfield** is not set yet, and the products where **newfield** is **NULL**, **string(0)** or **string(8) "NO FIELD"**.

PD: if only need one condition and do not need the **OR**, then it is enough with:

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
    ->getCollection()
    ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'newfield'))
    ->addAttributeToFilter('newfield', array('null' => true), 'left');
```

Comment: how to add attribute null filter in product list page i am not able how to solve it please help me . in which file add filter condition ?@Alex

Answer (score 2):

This code is getting product collection.
Suppose you have 100 product.
You update 10 product after attribute `newfield` created.
5 product update with 1 value and 5 product update with 0 value
So you got the 95 product in collection using this code.
5 + 90(rest of all)

---

```
$_products = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')
                         ->getCollection()
                         ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'newfield'))
                         ->addAttributeToFilter(
                             array(
                                 array('attribute'=> 'newfield','null' => true),
                                 array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => '1'),
                             ),
                             '',
                             'left');
```

Answer (score 0):

try to filter collection with attribute value `in_array`

```
->addAttributeToFilter('newfield', array('in' => $array));
```

where `$array = array(null,'');`

Answer (score 0):

```
 $collection->addAttributeToFilter('attribute_name', array('or'=> array(
             0 => array( 'neq' => '1'),
             1 => array('is' => new Zend_Db_Expr('null')))
         ), 'left');
```

It's working and get data not eq 1 and null value

Answer (score 0):

For magento 2, use the following code:

```
use \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\CollectionFactory;

$_products = $this->_productCollectionFactory->create()

 ->addAttributeToSelect(array('sku', 'name', 'newfield'))

 ->addAttributeToFilter(
  array(

    array('attribute'=> 'newfield','null' => true),

    array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => ''),

    array('attribute'=> 'newfield','eq' => 'NULL')

),

'',
'left');
```